# WebRequest.GetSystemWebProxy() doesn't include uri

Tags: .net, http, internet-explorer, proxy, internet-options

I'm trying to get the system proxy:

```
var proxy = WebRequest.GetSystemWebProxy();
```

However, the proxy object returned has its `Address` property always `null`.

The proxy is set in the *Internet Options* window.

[image: Internet Options Proxy Settings: 127.0.0.1: 8888]

Answer (score 0):

In msdn, it shows "GetSystemWebProxy method reads the current user's Internet Explorer (IE) proxy settings.".

So if you are developing a web app and deployed it to IIS, please check the identity of the app pool is same as the current user, which you have set the proxy. And make sure the IE proxy has been checked.

Comment: Thanks, I was using it in the IDE though so it was running under my credentials.